# Single parameter multiple records select statement sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to consolidate reports.  I have 2 identical reports using similar sql statements.  The only difference is the way the input parameter is used.

In the first report the user inputs the parent number (111) and it selects all child orders between 111.000 and 111.999.  If a user inputs the parent and child (ie 111.013), all children are returned from 111.013 to 111.999.

Statement 1:

```
SELECT ordernumber
FROM table1
WHERE  ordernumber >= $P{Parameter1} 
and ordernumber < $P{Parameter1} +'1'
```

The second statement selects only a single order given the parent and child (111.013).

Statement 2:

```
  SELECT ordernumber
    FROM table1
    WHERE  ordernumber = $P{Parameter1}
```

Is there a way to combine these statements to use the different inputs to get the correct output?

Comment: Assuming that these numbers are strings, your first SQL statement isn't going to do what you think it's doing. '1110' is going to be less than '111' + '1'. A better design would have avoided this whole mess, by keeping separate data in separate columns. The first and second portion of the order number look to be obviously different pieces of data.

Comment: How is the code to know what the user means when they send in '111.013'? That could mean either a single order or multiple orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in one more parameter, lets say $P{Parameter2}, which indicates which statement to be used. As in if $P{Parameter2} is true, use statement 1 else use statement 2. The following query can be used.

SELECT ordernumber
FROM table1
WHERE  (ordernumber >= $P{Parameter1}
and ordernumber < $P{Parameter1} +1 and $P{Parameter2}) or (ordernumber = $P{Parameter1} and  !$P{Parameter2})